# Export/list the control points of a NURBS

Tags: export, nurbs-surface

30 minutes ago, I launched `blender` for the first time. I'm rather overwhelmed by the options, so I dare to ask this novice question.

I'd like to export the control points of a NURBS into a text file. If possible I'd prefer homogeneous coordinates.

1. For the start, I have created a path and modified it to look like a quadratic Bezier curve.
2. I've exported to different formats, but didn't find NURBS data in them (e.g. `dae` file contains lamp and camera, `obj` contains coordinates of the curve).

> How can I obtain the control points and knot vector?

I found [this](https://gist.github.com/5263/2376960), but I'm not sure how to use it and if it could be helpful.

Comment: Its not clear for this question if you are asking about OBJ file format support or how to access the API to write this yourself.

Comment: Sorry, ideasman, indeed I don't care about .obj. All I want is a way to extract knots & control points. I would love a general solution involving api calls, since .obj provides only univariate NURBS data

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OBJ Format supports nurbs, but Blender writes them as edges by default (since many applications don't support them).

File -> Export -> Wavefront OBJ

Then in the options, enable **Write Nurbs**. This currently only supports Nurbs splines (not surfaces).

---

If for some reason you need to access different kinds of curve data, writing nurbs to a text file from Python isn't all that complicated.

Comment: ohh, I missed that checkbox! looks excellent.

Comment: On a side note: This seems to work only on univariate NURBS (i.e. curves and paths, but unfortunately not surfaces)