# Mesh curve to Nurbs

Tags: bezier-curves, nurbs-surface

I'm new here. I'm want ask you if there is the possibility to transform the curve that comes from subdivision surface (shown in the photo) in NURBS curve.

[image: Curve]

Comment: I don't think it's possible...

Comment: Blender does not have a very good NURBS modelling workflow, and I don't think you will be able to do this.

Answer (score 1):

One option to try is exporting your object in *.OBJ format with the NURBS checkbox ticked, as shown below.

[image]

Note that [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16190/export-list-the-control-points-of-a-nurbs/16191#16191) says that currently the export only supports Nurbs splines, not surfaces. This is confirmed by the Blender [webpage](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Import-Export/Wavefront_OBJ) on Wavefront file export.